# "Execution was interrupted, reasno: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" error as I try to make a GET request

Tags: swift, xcode, get, httprequest, urlsession

I am trying to run this in my playground:

```
func getWeatherForecast(){
let Endpoint : String =  "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/{}"
let url = URL(string:Endpoint)

let parameters = ["apikey":"API_KEY"] as [String:Any?]
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url:url!)
do
{urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
} catch {
    print("error")
}

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {(data, response, error) in
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        print("The Response is : ",json)
    } catch {
        print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
task.resume()
}
getWeatherForecast()
```

Then I keep getting the two following errors:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION 
(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use 
"thread return -x" to return to the state before expression
```

I have tried many variations of running this API call and I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. Can anyone help out here? I am just trying to make a simple GET but it seems to keep telling me "Fatal Error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" I feel that I have unwrapped correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In `with: data!`: data can be nil, and the app will crash. Check for nil value beforehand. Also it's better to first check if you received an error. If you did, no point to check data at all

Comment: @KirilS. So I removed the force unwrap and checked for Nil but I am still getting the same error. Also, do you mean to just check for error first before even trying to run the JSONserialization.

Comment: wait a second... it's not a request it's URL: `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/{}` is not a valid URL (square brackets are not allowed, should be escaped, if needed at all) E.g. `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/%7B%7D`

Comment: That seems to do the trick for that section. But I am still getting the same Nil error. This is happening somewhere after my task.resume(). Any idea? Am I handling the data incorrectly? EDIT: When I remove the ! from `data` it asks me to add !

Comment: you can always do `guard let data = data else { // data is nil, do something else }`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an "http" url which is blocked by Apple, because it is insecure. You have to use "https" or temporary allow that in the plist file.